# Ufw conficting with init systemd-sysv during install

Tags: debian, apt, kali-linux, ufw

I installed kali on my computer, but then I tried making it into a server, so I installed PHP, MySQL and apache2. I did some research and it told me to install UFW so I typed in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get ufw
```

here's the output:

```
root@kali-k:~# sudo apt-get install ufw



 Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      accountsservice apg appstream colord-data cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper
      dns-root-data dnsmasq-base eject exfat-fuse exfat-utils
      gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0
      gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
      gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
      gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-3.0
      gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
      gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2
      gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gnome-control-center-data gnome-session-bin
      gnome-session-common gnome-shell-common gnome-software-common gvfs-libs
      libaccountsservice0 libappstream-glib8 libappstream4 libatasmart4
      libcolord-gtk1 libcolorhug2 libcrack2 libdbd-mysql-perl libfwupd1
      libgail-3-0 libgcab-1.0-0 libgdm1 libgeoclue-2-0 libgnome-autoar-0-0
      libgnome-menu-3-0 libgtkspell3-3-0 libgusb2 libibus-1.0-5 libjim0.76
      libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9
      libmusicbrainz5-2 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libmutter0i libndp0 libnfs8
      libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0 libnma0 libnss-myhostname
      libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0
      libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libqmi-glib5
      libqmi-proxy libreadline6 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2
      librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libteamdctl0
      libtelepathy-logger3 libudisks2-0 libxcb-res0 mobile-broadband-provider-info
      modemmanager mousetweaks mutter mutter-common nautilus-data php7.0-mysql
      python3-software-properties rygel software-properties-common
      software-properties-gtk unattended-upgrades usb-modeswitch
      usb-modeswitch-data wpasupplicant xwayland
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    The following packages will be REMOVED:
      chrome-gnome-shell colord dbus-user-session ettercap-graphical gdm3
      gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-disk-utility gnome-session
      gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock
      gnome-shell-extension-easyscreencast gnome-shell-extension-proxyswitcher
      gnome-shell-extension-workspacestodock gnome-shell-extensions gnome-software
      gnome-sushi gnome-tweak-tool gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse
      iio-sensor-proxy init libpam-systemd nautilus network-manager
      network-manager-gnome packagekit packagekit-tools policykit-1 rtkit systemd
      systemd-sysv udisks2
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      ufw
    WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
    This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
      init systemd-sysv (due to init)
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 36 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 138 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 78.9 MB disk space will be freed.
    You are about to do something potentially harmful.
    To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do not run this. You will render the entire system unbootable by removing `systemd` and other core components.

Comment: Also, making Kali into a server is a _really_ bad idea. Do you know that everything is run as `root`?

Comment: "_I installed kali on my computer, but then I tried making it into a server,_". Don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

In short:

- The package manager here is prompting you to remove a bunch of essential packages, which will make your system unusable. This is very ill-advised and should not happen unless the source repos are messed up.
- Kali is a distro for pentesting, it is not aimed at all to function as any kind of server.
- Furthermore, Kali is not intended for Linux neophytes.

You should wipe out Kali, forget it and install either Debian or Ubuntu to start experiencing with Linux.